# Why does Google Sign In with Basecamps Gem not work in Google Cloud Run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-signin, google-cloud-run

I just came across a strange Rails Cloud Run relation bug so I am posting here in case others run into it. I am using Basecamp's Google Sign In gem to authenticate with Google (https://github.com/basecamp/google_sign_in). Everything worked fine in development however when I pushed to production on Google Cloud Run it failed and refused to work. My code is

```
if id_token = flash[:google_sign_in][:id_token]
     find_or_create_user_from_google_authentication(id_token)
elsif error = flash[:google_sign_in][:error]
    logger.error "Google authentication error: #{error}"
    nil
end
```

which is very similar to the suggested code in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis it turns out that

`flash[:google_sign_in][:id_token]`

returns nil on Cloud Run however

`flash[:google_sign_in]`

has a stringified hash value like `{ "token_id" => "uiagskawgkasdgkudsag..."}` meaning that

`flash[:google_sign_in]["id_token"]`

works. I have no idea why it is stringifying it and especially why it only stringifies the nested hash key and it took a while to figure out so I hope it helps if you also come across this strange bug.